# Is there a way to overwrite the CSS of apex components in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I'm using a pageBlock component, it's obviously very handy for storing my returned object/s but I really don't like how it looks. As I'm quite new to apex/salesforce, I'm wondering is there a way to overwrite the styles attached to the pageBlock?

Is there a convention for it? Or can I even use a regular html table in it's place?

```
        <apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!attachments}" var="attach" id="attachmentsTable">

               <apex:column >
                   <apex:outputText value="{!attach.name}"/>
               </apex:column>                  

               <apex:column >
                   <apex:outputText value="{!attach.description}"/>
               </apex:column> 

               <apex:column >
                   <apex:outputLink styleClass="actionLink" target="_BLANK" value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!attach.Id}">View</apex:outputLink>
               </apex:column> 

           </apex:pageBlockTable> 

         </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that salesforce does not guarantee the output html or their css to be the same in new releases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can overwrite it with your own CSS, just don't forget to insert `!important`. Or you can assign your own css class to the components using `styleClass="myCssClass"` parameter.

Of course you can create your own pure HTML table and iterate through **attachments** list using `apex:repeat` tag:

```
<table>
    <apex:repeat value="{!attachments}" var="attach">
        <tr>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{!attach.name}"/></td>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{!attach.description}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah!! Good lad mast0r!! This is exactly what I need! Cheers!!